# C++ Implementing states

Tags: c++, sfml

My question is:
I am trying to implement basic state management in my project and i stuck at changing states.
I have all my states in `std::stack<State*>` container, and push/pop them directly from Application class or from State class.
Problem is when i change current state from State class, it can be destroyed before render method called, whitch results in exeption. So how do i avoid this?
PS sorry for my english and please say me if something in my problem/code isn clear

Application class:

```
void Application::pushState(State* state)
{
    this->m_states.push(state);
    this->m_states.top()->open();//enter state
}

void Application::popState()
{
    if (!this->m_states.empty())
    {
        this->m_states.top()->close();//leave state
        delete this->m_states.top();
    }

    if (!this->m_states.empty())
    this->m_states.pop();
}

void Application::changeState(State* state)
{
    if (!this->m_states.empty())
        popState();
    pushState(state);
}

State* Application::peekState()
{
    if (this->m_states.empty()) return nullptr;
    return this->m_states.top();
}

void Application::mainLoop()
{
    sf::Clock clock;

    while (this->m_window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Time elapsed = clock.restart();
        float delta = elapsed.asSeconds();

        if (this->peekState() == nullptr)
            this->m_window.close();
        this->peekState()->update(delta)//if i change state in State.update(), it may be that code below will now point to not existing state

        if (this->peekState() == nullptr)
            this->m_window.close();
        this->peekState()->render(delta);
    }
}
```

State class:

```
void EditorState::update(const float delta)
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (this->m_application->m_window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            this->m_application->popState();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Okay maybe this is not really a problem, but something like "how to" question. As you can see in my code, i update and render states in mainLoop() method. What im tying to figure out is how to manage those updates, asuming that state can be changed from state itself, not only from stateManager (in my case Application class)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Are you sure that a stack is the right data structure to hold states? You might be interested in [this](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/).

Comment: Not sure, maybe i can change it to vector, but overall this is not what my problem is i think

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Okay maybe this is not really a problem, but something like "how to" question. As you can see in my code, i update and render states in mainLoop() method. What im tying to figure out is how to manage those updates, asuming that state can be changed from state itself, not only from stateManager (in my case Application class)

Comment: You can check how I've done it in the STTCL framework I linked you. It's not actually rocket science.

Comment: What is the purpose of a stack for your states? Does your program have an undo feature? If not, will a single state variable suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I'm guessing this is for a game (but it doesn't have to be). Instead of doing what you're doing for switching between states, I use an enum.

```
enum class GameState {
    MENU, PLAY, PAUSE
}
```

Then, in your main header

```
GameState m_gameState = GameState::MENU;
```

In your main loop, you can check what the current state is by simply doing

```
if (m_gameState == GameState::MENU)
{
    ...
}
```

or you can use a switch statement

```
switch (m_gameState)
{
case GameState::MENU:
    ...
    break;
case GameState::PLAY:
    ...
    break;
case GameState::PAUSE:
    ...
    break;
}
```

And, if you ever want to switch the state, you can just do

```
m_gameState = GameState::PAUSE;
```

Hope this answered your question :D

If not, I must have misunderstood (sorry).

Comment: This is an ok solution but this could easily flood the main loop with behaviour that is not its' responsibility. With the approach @powerglove is taking he can separate that into another class.

Comment: You can separate this into another class if you'd like, it's not restricted to only the one class. (Also @powerglove if this worked as an answer, be sure to mark it, thanks)